# Show a new ToC in a subsection with Beamer

Tags: table-of-contents

First at all, I'm preparing a presentation with BEAMER.

I would like to show a principal ToC with section an subsections and when arrive to a subsetion slide, show a new ToC exclusive along this subsection. That is:

-Section 1

---Subsection 1.1

---Subsection 1.2

-Section 2

---Subsection 2.1

---Subsection 2.2

and when starts slide Subsection 2.2 that will appear a new ToC  only showed in this subsection 2.2, with different subsubsections.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you looked at any packages like [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) or [minitoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc?lang=en)? What have you tried so far? You mentioned "slides" – are you using beamer?

Comment: Yes, I forgot advice that I'm using Beamer. Apologies for that.